# Hard binomial lattice requests (color, arrows and more)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish to replicate the image in this post. However I can't do any of it except the basic stuff that my code does. Thanks for any help.

The exact coloring doesn't matter. Also I don't actually want those black lines around the coloring. Perhaps a darker blue line around the light blue coloring and a darker green line around the light green coloring.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,backgrounds,calc}



 \begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,sloped]
    \matrix (tree) [%
      matrix of nodes,
      minimum size=1cm,
      column sep=3.5cm,
      row sep=0.6cm,
    ]
    {
             & |(top-left)| & |(top-right)|     & $ $  \\
              &                    &  $_0S_{2\Delta t}$   &       \\
              & $_0S_{\Delta t}$   &                      & $ $           \\
      $_0S_0$ &                    &  $_1S_{2\Delta t}$   &       \\
              & $_1S_{\Delta t}$   &                      & $ $       \\
              &                    &  $_2S_{2\Delta t}$   &     \\
              & |(bottom-left)|    &  |(bottom-right)|    & $ $   \\              
    };
    \draw[->] (tree-4-1) -- (tree-3-2) node [midway,above] {$p$};
    \draw[->] (tree-4-1) -- (tree-5-2) node [midway,below] {$1-p$};
    \draw[->] (tree-3-2) -- (tree-2-3) node [midway,above](a) {};
    \draw[->] (tree-3-2) -- (tree-4-3) node [midway,below] {};
    \draw[->] (tree-5-2) -- (tree-4-3) node [midway,above] {};
    \draw[->] (tree-5-2) -- (tree-6-3) node [midway,below] {};
    \draw[->,dashed,shorten >= 17mm] (tree-2-3) -- (tree-1-4) node [midway,above] {};
    \draw[->,dashed,shorten >= 17mm] (tree-2-3) -- (tree-3-4) node [midway,below] {};
    \draw[->,dashed,shorten >= 17mm] (tree-4-3) -- (tree-3-4) node [midway,above] {};
    \draw[->,dashed,shorten >= 17mm] (tree-4-3) -- (tree-5-4) node [midway,below] {};
    \draw[->,dashed,shorten >= 17mm] (tree-6-3) -- (tree-5-4) node [midway,above] {};
    \draw[->,dashed,shorten >= 17mm] (tree-6-3) -- (tree-7-4) node [midway,below] {};

    % t-line
    \draw[dashed] ($(top-left.north)!.5!(top-right.north)$) -- ($(bottom-left.south)!.5!(bottom-right.south)$);
    \node at ($(bottom-left.south)!.5!(bottom-right.south)-(0,1em)$) {$\tau$};


  \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, you already loaded all the right libraries:

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,backgrounds,calc}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,sloped]
    \matrix (tree)
    [   matrix of nodes,
    minimum size=1cm,
    column sep=3.5cm,
    row sep=0.6cm,
  ]
  {         & |(top-left)|       & |(top-right)|        & $ $ \\
            &                    &  $_0S_{2\Delta t}$   &     \\
            & $_0S_{\Delta t}$   &                      & $ $ \\
    $_0S_0$ &                    &  $_1S_{2\Delta t}$   &     \\
            & $_1S_{\Delta t}$   &                      & $ $ \\
            &                    &  $_2S_{2\Delta t}$   &     \\
            & |(bottom-left)|    &  |(bottom-right)|    & $ $ \\              
    };
    \draw[->] (tree-4-1) -- (tree-3-2) node [midway,above] {$p$};
    \draw[->] (tree-4-1) -- (tree-5-2) node [midway,below] {$1-p$};
    \draw[->] (tree-3-2) -- (tree-2-3) node [midway,above](a) {};
    \draw[->] (tree-3-2) -- (tree-4-3) node [midway,below] {};
    \draw[->] (tree-5-2) -- (tree-4-3) node [midway,above] {};
    \draw[->] (tree-5-2) -- (tree-6-3) node [midway,below] {};
    \draw[->,dashed,shorten >= 17mm] (tree-2-3) -- (tree-1-4) node [midway,above] {};
    \draw[->,dashed,shorten >= 17mm] (tree-2-3) -- (tree-3-4) node [midway,below] {};
    \draw[->,dashed,shorten >= 17mm] (tree-4-3) -- (tree-3-4) node [midway,above] {};
    \draw[->,dashed,shorten >= 17mm] (tree-4-3) -- (tree-5-4) node [midway,below] {};
    \draw[->,dashed,shorten >= 17mm] (tree-6-3) -- (tree-5-4) node [midway,above] {};
    \draw[->,dashed,shorten >= 17mm] (tree-6-3) -- (tree-7-4) node [midway,below] {};

    % t-line
    \draw[dashed] ($(top-left.north)!.5!(top-right.north)$) -- ($(bottom-left.south)!.5!(bottom-right.south)$);

    % color backgrounds
    \node at ($(bottom-left.south)!.5!(bottom-right.south)-(0,1em)$) {$\tau$};
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background layer}
            \node[fit=(tree-2-3)(tree-4-3), fill=blue!50!cyan, rounded corners=0.2cm, inner sep=0, opacity=0.5] {};
            \node[fit=(tree-4-3)(tree-6-3), fill=green!50!lime, rounded corners=0.2cm, inner sep=0, opacity=0.5] {};
            \node[fit=(tree-3-2), fill=blue!50!cyan, rounded corners=0.2cm, inner sep=0, opacity=0.5] {};
            \node[fit=(tree-5-2), fill=green!50!lime, rounded corners=0.2cm, inner sep=0, opacity=0.5] {};
        \end{pgfonlayer}

    \draw[->,blue!50!cyan, shorten >=5mm, shorten <=6mm] ($(tree-2-3)+(0,0.1)$) -- ($(tree-3-2)+(0,0.1)$) node[pos=0.3,above,sloped] {x=k};

    \node[blue!50!cyan] at ($0.33*(tree-3-2)+0.33*(tree-2-3)+0.33*(tree-4-3)$) {Step 1};
    \node[green!50!lime] at ($0.33*(tree-5-2)+0.33*(tree-4-3)+0.33*(tree-6-3)$) {Step 2};

  \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

### Result

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Another coloring approach:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,backgrounds,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,sloped]
    \matrix (tree)
    [   matrix of nodes,
    minimum size=1cm,
    column sep=3.5cm,
    row sep=0.6cm,
  ]
  {         & |(top-left)|       & |(top-right)|        & $ $ \\
            &                    &  $_0S_{2\Delta t}$   &     \\
            & $_0S_{\Delta t}$   &                      & $ $ \\
    $_0S_0$ &                    &  $_1S_{2\Delta t}$   &     \\
            & $_1S_{\Delta t}$   &                      & $ $ \\
            &                    &  $_2S_{2\Delta t}$   &     \\
            & |(bottom-left)|    &  |(bottom-right)|    & $ $ \\              
    };
    \draw[->] (tree-4-1) -- (tree-3-2) node [midway,above] {$p$};
    \draw[->] (tree-4-1) -- (tree-5-2) node [midway,below] {$1-p$};
    \draw[->] (tree-3-2) -- (tree-2-3) node [midway,above](a) {};
    \draw[->] (tree-3-2) -- (tree-4-3) node [midway,below] {};
    \draw[->] (tree-5-2) -- (tree-4-3) node [midway,above] {};
    \draw[->] (tree-5-2) -- (tree-6-3) node [midway,below] {};
    \draw[->,dashed,shorten >= 17mm] (tree-2-3) -- (tree-1-4) node [midway,above] {};
    \draw[->,dashed,shorten >= 17mm] (tree-2-3) -- (tree-3-4) node [midway,below] {};
    \draw[->,dashed,shorten >= 17mm] (tree-4-3) -- (tree-3-4) node [midway,above] {};
    \draw[->,dashed,shorten >= 17mm] (tree-4-3) -- (tree-5-4) node [midway,below] {};
    \draw[->,dashed,shorten >= 17mm] (tree-6-3) -- (tree-5-4) node [midway,above] {};
    \draw[->,dashed,shorten >= 17mm] (tree-6-3) -- (tree-7-4) node [midway,below] {};

    % t-line
    \draw[dashed] ($(top-left.north)!.5!(top-right.north)$) -- ($(bottom-left.south)!.5!(bottom-right.south)$);
    \node at ($(bottom-left.south)!.5!(bottom-right.south)-(0,1em)$) {$\tau$};

    % background
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \draw[rounded corners,draw=none,top color=blue!40!cyan!60, bottom color=green!60!lime!50](tree-2-3.north west)rectangle(tree-6-3.south east);
    \draw[rounded corners,draw=none,fill=blue!40!cyan!60](tree-3-2.north west)rectangle(tree-3-2.south east);
    \draw[rounded corners,draw=none,fill=green!60!lime!50](tree-5-2.north west)rectangle(tree-5-2.south east);
    \end{pgfonlayer}

 \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Didn't add arrow stuff since Tom's answer already solved that. `:)`